# Rails "array" in xml to params

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, parameters

I am designing a rails rest API that I would like to expose either as xml or json. In a specific action, I am submitting a collection of objects like this:

```
curl -d "<posts><post><title>my title</title></post><post><title>second post</title></post></posts>" localhost:3000/posts -X POST
```

I thought that this would be translated into

```
> params[:posts]
[{:title => "my title"}, {:title => "second post"}]
```

Instead of that I get

```
 {:post => [{:title => "my title"}, {:title => "second post"}]}
```

The question is then how should I format my xml such that I get this in params[:posts] ?

```
[{:title => "my title"}, {:title => "second post"}]
```

I know how to do it in functional tests and json but not xml :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the XML in your curl starts with:

```
<posts></post>...
```

rather than:

```
<posts><post>...
```

Edit:

Posting XML as an array in Rails requires type="array" to be added to the array node.

```
<posts type="array"><post>...
```

Comment: Updated. Was just a typo to my question.

Comment: I'm guessing params[:posts][:post] is returning the array of posts you're wanting to access via params[:posts].

Comment: Try: `<posts type="array"><post>...`