# Rails not getting params from HTTP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to `POST` the following data to a Rails server (running on WebRick) from Android.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<data>
  <email>email.test@name.com</email>
  <password>APassw0rd</password>
  <remember_me>1</remember_me>
</data>
```

Now, the funny thing is that these data never show up in the `params` field in the controller.
Webrick does not output any parsing error. (And I guess it would post an error if it received a `POST` with no data attached:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in.xml" for 192.168.1.94 at 2012-12-14 17:33:20 +0100
Processing by Users::SessionController#create as XML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22643ms
```

I also found no trace of the data in the `request.env` variable. Actually, I see no `HTTP_BODY` in the dump fields. How can one see the raw body of the request? Would webrick really not complain if it received a `POST` with no attached data?

Comment: You can certainly send a POST request with no attached data. I'm not too familiar with XML stuff but if possible can you post your logs from webrick? Are you actually hitting the right controller action?

Comment: I'm hitting the right controller (I put a breakpoint there) and I can dump the request.env to see all the fields of the request. Everything is fine except for the missing data.

Comment: just added the webrick log to the post.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424063/rails-array-in-xml-to-params

Comment: You're getting a 500 error so that means you're crashing somewhere in your controller action. Can you post that snippet?

Comment: Yes I'm crashing because of the mising params. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.env` would show the data as an IO object so you wouldn't be able to see your xml directly.

`request.raw_post` should return the raw data.

For rails to try and parse your xml into the params hash directly you need to set the content type of the request to application/xml. The 'processing as xml' stuff means that rails will try to render an xml response and doesn't necessarily have any bearing on the format of the posted data

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do set "Content-Type" to "application/xml" in the request.

Comment: Are you certain the data is being posted properly ? (for example, maybe use tcpdump or similar to capture what bytes are being sent)

Comment: Ok I tried to change the HTTP header from `application/xml` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and I can see in the rails controller the data. See [Screenshot here](http://dwingeloo.free.fr/sshotrailsparams.png).

Comment: So now, why is webrick discarding the whole thing and not parsing it? What format/HTTP headers does it expect?

Comment: I think rails will only parse xml similar to what to_xml on activerecord objects generate. Not sure though

Comment: Hmm. You mean I have to match ALL the fields of a given model? That sounds odd.

Comment: No - I mean the overall shape of the XML.